# Transactions on Managed Beans

Tags: jsf, jpa, ejb, managed-bean, jta

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am working on a WEB application that uses JAVA EE6 , more precisely with JPA, JSF and EJB. In a JSF page i call a method to save data onto database.In the Managed Bean i have the following method :

```
 @ManagedProperty(value = "#{jndi['ejb/objectEAO']}")
 private ObjectEAO objectEAO;

 public void save(){
      ...
     for(Type1 type : list){
         if(..){
             ....
            objectEAO.save(type);
          }
      }
  }
```

My question is: 
   Is the save method transactional by default ? If the third insert fails for some reason , is the all process rollbacked ?
   The objectEAO is a EJB.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save()` method in EJB bean is transactional (assuming CMT - Container Managed Transactions), not the one in your JSF managed bean. So, if one insert fails it will rollback only that one operation, without impacting previous inserts.

Comment: Are you sure?  I would have expected if there is a transaction active when ObjectEAO.save() is called, the changes and enlisted in that transaction, and if there isn't then they're all combined into one transaction which commits when ObjectEAO.save() returns?

Comment: @hugh It is unlikely that transaction is already active in JSF managed bean (unless Open Session In View pattern is used). That means managed bean is simply a client which calls EJB service in a loop, and if CMT is used (the default behavior for EJBs) then the container starts the transaction before service call and closes it at the end. There is no mechanism that would join all calls into one transaction.